# How to manage Windows Instance remotely from Mac Terminal?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-access, amazon-ec2

I would like to manage AWS Windows instance from Mac via terminal.  Managing includes installing some packages on Windows instance.

How can I achieve this without RDP (like some scripting)?

Thanks

Comment: You can use two app.

Comment: If you're open to installing `cygwin` or another package that includes an `ssh` server, you would then be able to do that.  I don't know if `winexe` or `psexec` has a version that can run on a Mac, but those might be options too.  Also, you might try this question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead of here if you don't get much attention here

Comment: Microsoft Remote Desktop and CoRD: Simple RDP Remote Desktop. Using this application you can also write a script to open this in command line. CORD helps to use rdp://hostname.

Comment: CoRD is look like GUI based tool but I am looking for script based tools which I can run once in a month automatically.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @TechieGossip is it ok if i simply copy the question from one forum to another ?

Comment: @kid if you want to move the question to another forum you should flag it and ask the moderators to move it for you, cross posting is discouraged on SE sites

Comment: Your question does not meet the migration requirement for SoftwareRecs.

Comment: Please read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).